# How dangerous would a green anole be to a human if it was 12:1 scale, 12 times bigger(barring the negative effects of the square-cube law)?

Tags: fauna, reptiles

So I was thinking about a world where [green anoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anolis_carolinensis) somehow get bigger(and change a bit), about 12 times their normal size. How much danger would an adult human be in if it got aggressive? In this world, whatever made them bigger also negated the negative effects of scaling-up an animal, so do not apply that law here too much.

Comment: Do you want your giant green anoles to have 12 times the volume and mass and thus about 2.3 times the dimensions, or do you want them to have 12 times the dimensions and thus 1,728 times the volume and mass of normal green anoles?  The second option would be 144 times as massive as he first option and considerably more dangerous..

Comment: Everything according to square-cube law.except the negatives i.e the later. @M.A.Golding .

Answer (score 3):

A green anole is reported to reach a length of about 8 inches, or 20 cm.

12 times that means 2.4 meters.

For reference, a [Komodo dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_dragon) can reach up to 3 meters. And how are they with respect to humans?

> Attacks on humans are rare, but Komodo dragons have been responsible for several human fatalities, in both the wild and in captivity. According to data from Komodo National Park spanning a 38-year period between 1974 and 2012, there were 24 reported attacks on humans, five of them fatal. Most of the victims were local villagers living around the national park.

Not as dangerous as a crocodile or an alligator, but surely not totally harmless.

Comment: but they are very much subject to the square cube law. They are much more massive, and therefore probably slower and not as active as anoles. (i don't know anoles, but i image them to move like geckos)

Comment: Like I said, barring the negative effects of that law. @ths

Comment: Were talking about the Komodos being affected? @ths

Comment: yes of course..

Answer (score 0):

Given the metabolic needs of a creature over 2 metres in length, even a lizard, it's not going to be primarily an insectivore anymore (unless there are giant spiders, and there should never, but ***never***, be giant spiders), and, without changing it quite a lot, it's not really equipped as a true carnivore. Anoles already eat some vegetable matter in the form of grains and seeds in the wild. A 2+ metre anole is probably going to be an omnivore subsisting primarily on seeds/grains and nuts with a sideline in carrion whenever it can find it. Omnivores are often quite hostile when cornered because they don't depend on hunting, so are less worried about injury than pure carnivores but are capable of eating what they kill, if they have to kill. So while they're relatively poorly equipped to injury or kill they will be hard to discourage once they've committed to an attack which still makes an aggressive one dangerous.

Comment: I was thinking about them being herbivores, mostly frugivores, so I guess I was on the science on that part. The spider part was funny, lol! Was supprised about the omnivore aggression level part.

Comment: @ConanHighwoods It's what makes bears more dangerous to humans than big cats. Bears don't have to be on top of their game to survive so they'll risk injury, or even get injured and keep going, where a big cat will back down to avoid an injury that means they can't hunt at peak performance.